# Android: Cannot resolve symbol "id"

Tags: java, android

I am currently following the Google documents for Android programming. I am at the part where I need to perform a task when a button is pressed on the action bar. Here is the code I have:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_search:
            openSearch();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            openSettings();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


    }

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

However on if(id == R.id.action_settings), I get an error saying that the symbol r can not be resolved. What could be causing this as it all looks fine to me.

Comment: Are you using android studio?

Comment: Yes I am using Android Studio.

Comment: Have you tried just running it anyway? Occasionally I get weird messages like this, but if I run it it works fine and the message disappears later.

Comment: How does it matter what IDE he is using? This code won't compile.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski No, that's not right. I've encountered this bug in android studio before. `R.id` is turned red for no reason, but the code compiles and runs perfectly. I'm not saying that's necessarily the OP's issue.

Comment: Read the source. It will NOT compile.

Comment: `if (id == R.id.action_settings)` ... Try: `if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings)` instead

Comment: Geezz... @JoeMurphy see the answer......

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Fair enough, the variable `id` is not declared, but the OP's question says that the symbol r cannot be resolved. There is a bug in  android studio where `R` is sometimes not recognised, so it wasn't an unreasonable question.

Comment: I am not saying that question is unreasonable. I am saying I woudl assume his IDE underlines WHOLE condition, due to `id`, not just R.... thing

Answer (score 2):

Aside from missing `id` which renders OP's broken, anything below `switch()` is simply [dead code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code) and can be safely removed (I'd bet your IDE is already flagging you this anyway):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_search:
            openSearch();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            openSettings();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

> I get an error saying that the symbol r can not be resolved.

Not seeing real error message, I'd assume the complain here is due to the `id` but **if** it's really about `R`, then check `import` section to see if you got `import android.R` there. If so, remove it and try again.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
```

Won't compile because you are not declaring what `id` is anywhere before that.

Did you delete `int id = item.getItemId();` by accident?

Edit : that whole if condition is redundant anyways, you are handling `action_settings` in code before.